# How do I adapt my code for multiprocessing

Tags: python

Whenever I use my (other) multiprocessing code it works fine but in terms of feedback for where I am in regards to completion of the script for example "Completed 5 / 10 files" I do not know how to adapt my code to return the count. Basically I would like to adapt the code below to allow multiprocessing.

So I Use

```
file_paths = r"path to file with paths"
count = 0
pool = Pool(16)
pool.map(process_control, file_paths)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

within process_control I have at the end of the function `count += 1 and return count`

I guess the equivelant code would be something like

```
def process_control(count, file_path):
    do stuff
    count += 1
    print("Process {} / {} completed".format(count, len(file_paths))
    return count


file_paths = r"path to file with paths" 
count = 0 
for path in file_paths:
    count = process_control(count, path)
```

SOmething like that so that. I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: Try "pool.imap" or "imap_unordered" with a for-loop in the main process (maybe in a separate thread if necessary). In the loop you can then increment the counter and print the count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each subprocess has its own copy of `count` so all they can do is track the work in that one process. The count won't aggregate for all of the processes. But the parent can do the counting. `map` waits for all tasks to complete, so that isn't helpful. `imap` is better, it iterates but it also maintains order so reporting is still delayed. `imap_unordered` with chunksize 1 is your best option. Each task return value (even if it is None) is returned immediately.

```
def process_control(count, file_path):
    do stuff

file_paths = ["path1", ...]
with multiprocessing.Pool(16) as pool:
    count = 0
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(porcess_control, file_paths,chunksize=1):
         count += 1
        print("Process {} / {} completed".format(count, len(file_paths))
```

A note on `chunksize`. There are costs to using a pool - each work item needs to be sent to the subprocess and its value returned. This back-and-forth IPC is relatively expensive, so the pool will "chunk" the work items, meaning that it will send many work items to a given subprocess all in one chunk and the process will only return when the entire chunk of data has been processed through the worker function.

This is great when there are many relatively short work items. But suppose that different work items take different amount of time to execute. There will be a tall-pole subprocess still working on its chunk even though the others have finished.

More important for your case, the results aren't posted back to the parent until the chunk completes so you don't get real-time reporting of completion.

Set chunksize to 1 and the subprocess will return results immediately for more accurate accounting.

Comment: Cheers for the help  Ive had a look at chunksize but I am a bit unsure of what it does. If you are not too busy would you be able to provide a lamens explanation of what it does?

Answer (score 1):

For simple cases, the previous answer by @tedelaney is excellent.

For more complicated cases, [`Value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) provides shared memroy:

```
from multiprocessing import Value

counter = Value('i', 0)

# increment the value
with variable.get_lock():
    counter.value += 1

# get the value.  Read lock automatically used
processes_done = counter.value
```